# RuntimeError: Assertion `THIndexTensor_(size)(target, 0) == batch_size' failed. at ...ClassNLLCriterion.c:79

Tags: conv-neural-network, pytorch, assertion

I am working on a machine learning project. My task is to classify satellite images. I have 5 classes as my labels. The whole data is in Matlab format.
Posting the whole code would be too much, so I have decided to post the important part of it.

Here is the code-snippet:

```python
...

from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F


class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 5 * 5, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 5)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = x.view(-1, 16 * 5 * 5)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x


net = Net()


import torch.optim as optim

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

for epoch in range(2):  # loop over the dataset multiple times

    running_loss = 0.0
    for i in range(1):
        print(i)
        # get the inputs
        #inputs, labels = data
        inputs=in_data
        labels=in_labels
        print("A:",labels.shape)
        print("B:",inputs.shape)


        # wrap them in Variable
        inputs, labels = Variable(inputs), Variable(labels)
        print("A_2:",inputs.size())
        print("A_3:",labels.size())

        # zero the parameter gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # forward + backward + optimize
        outputs = net(inputs)
        labels = labels.squeeze_()
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

...
```

As you can easily see, this a CNN (Convolutional Neural Network). If I run my code, following error(s) will be shown:

```python
0
A: torch.Size([100])
B: torch.Size([100, 3, 64, 64])
A_2: torch.Size([100, 3, 64, 64])
A_3: torch.Size([100])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "datasetAnalyser.py", line 283, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "datasetAnalyser.py", line 139, in main
    run(torchImage,torchLabel)
  File "datasetAnalyser.py", line 114, in run
    loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
  File "/home/qais/anaconda2/envs/Python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 325, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/qais/anaconda2/envs/Python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py", line 601, in forward
    self.ignore_index, self.reduce)
  File "/home/qais/anaconda2/envs/Python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 1140, in cross_entropy
    return nll_loss(log_softmax(input, 1), target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce)
  File "/home/qais/anaconda2/envs/Python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 1049, in nll_loss
    return torch._C._nn.nll_loss(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce)
RuntimeError: Assertion `THIndexTensor_(size)(target, 0) == batch_size' failed.  at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1513368888240/work/torch/lib/THNN/generic/ClassNLLCriterion.c:79
```

Well,I have googled and found many threads about this problem. Somehow, none of them solved my issue. That's why I ask you again.

What should I do? I guess I have to change the integer values in the

```python
class Net(nn.Module)
```

but I don't exactly know which values should be changed.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The error is definitely caused by the incompatible size between the `labels` and `outputs`. I am curious why you would use `label = label.squeeze_()`. I think it is unnecessary.

Try to remove `label = label.squeeze_()` and adjust the size of `labels` to match the `outputs`. This is a [good tutorial](http://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transfer_learning_tutorial.html#sphx-glr-beginner-transfer-learning-tutorial-py) about image classification. You can learn how they do it.

Comment: Where can I adjust the size of my labels in the code? Can you show me the significant line(s)?

Comment: @user2379123 try to remove the squeeze line and see if the code can work.

Comment: What is the size of output and label? Try to debug on that direction.

Comment: Labels: torch.Size([100])
Outputs: torch.Size([676, 100])

Comment: @user2379123 according to your class definition, there are 5 classes. The size of output should be [5, 100] or something.